# Which OpenOffice version has a reasonable Javascript support?

Tags: javascript, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I just started checking out OpenOffice's Macro system. I have 3.2.0 installed but it really sucks. I can't even save a macro file... I assume Javascript is not the recommended scripting language for Openoffice.

Still... Has anyone done OO-Macros with Javascript? Which OO-Version do you use? And besides: Which Javascript version is implemented? I wonder if that is an implentation that deserves the name Javascript because there is not even an alert()-function.

Philip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alert()` function is not a Javascript feature anyway; it's a method on the de-facto standard browser "window" object.

OpenOffice Javascript scripting uses Rhino; I'm not sure what version. The Rhino that ships with the JDK is pretty old and has some fairly severe bugs, but is still OK for the kinds of things you'd do with an OpenOffice script probably.

It appears that you have to install the Javascript runtime separately: http://framework.openoffice.org/scripting/release-0.2/javascript-devguide.html

Comment: I see... I already found a code snippet for a message box so I got that one. Actually I am already able to run code after installing some packages and clicking around, so I guess I don't need to install that Javascript runtime?!

Comment: Maybe it's packaged with the newer developer releases, or release candidates, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The last version of libreofffice have a support of the javascript macro. You can download it here : http://www.libreoffice.org/download/